# Как считать с информацию с Word'овского файла и записать в массив?

Tags: c#

Если можно, с хорошими примерами. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще это делается так: [Reading a word document using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Globalking/fileAccessingusingcsharp02242006050207AM/fileAccessingusingcsharp.aspx), а для общего развития можете почитать еще и тут: [Extracting Data from Word Tables Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149(v=office.11).aspx#officewordautomatingtablesdata_extractingdatafromatable).